# JPA query with count aggregate function

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I have two entities `A` and `B` as below:

```java
@Entity
public class A {
   @Id
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private boolean hasFailedChild;

   @OneToMany
   private List<B> bs;

   public A(String name, long count) {
      this.name = name;
      this.hasFailedChild = (count > 0);
   }
}

@Entity
public class B {
   @id
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String status;
   @ManyToOne
   private A a;

   //required constructors
}
```

I am trying to get all `A`s along with the its `B`s count with `Failed` status using `@Query`.

I have tried with the below Query:

```java
public interface ARepository extends CrudRepository<A, Integer> {

   @Query(value = "select new A(a.name, count(b)) " +
            "from A a left join a.bs b where b.status = 'Failed'")
   List<A> findAllA();
}
```

However, it is not working. Can someone help me here.

Comment: You have a default constructor for `A`, don't you?

Comment: Yes, I have. If I need to create any other constructors also, I can create them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should correct your query in the following way:

```sql
select new A(a.name, count(b))
from A a
left join a.bs b
where b.status = 'Failed'
group by a.name
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions) for additional details.